# JS Get day next month starts on

Tags: javascript, date

How can I get the day that the next month starts on? (Monday Tuesday etc.).

I tried the following but it returns more than just the day.

```js
var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);
```

Comment: *"...but it returns more than just the day."* What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, just add this after your last line of code to get the name of the day

```
var dayName = lastDay.toLocaleDateString('en-us', { weekday: 'long' });
```

Also keep in mind that `Date` constructor's second parameter is `monthIndex` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date).

You should add `m` by 1 to get next month's first day and add it by 2 and provide `date = 0` to get the last day of the next month.

```js
var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
var firstDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 1);
var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 2, 0);
var firstDayName = firstDay .toLocaleDateString('en-us', { weekday: 'long' }); 
var lastDayName = lastDay.toLocaleDateString('en-us', { weekday: 'long' }); 
console.log(firstDayName, lastDayName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is getting `Date` instances for the first and last day of the **current** month. So first you'll need to fix that. Then, if you want day numbers instead, you have to call `getDay` to get the values (0 = Sunday through 6 = Saturday):

```js
const today = new Date();
const year = today.getFullYear();
const month = today.getMonth() + 1; // + 1 = next month
const firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay();
const lastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDay();
console.log({firstDay, lastDay});
```

As I write this on July 31st, that shows `1` and `3`, telling us that August 2022 starts on Monday and ends on Wednesday.

Answer (score 0):

I just took the current date and got the first day of the month. Then we just converted this to string. It's working. Try this:

```js
const date = new Date(); // current date 1/8/2022
const nextMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 1); //first day of next month
const nextMonthStartDay = nextMonth.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long' }); //convert to date string
console.log(nextMonthStartDay) //Thursday
```